# Available Options for Mobile Development

Tags: android, mobile

I am interested in starting Mobile application Development.There are many suggestions on internet but,I wanted to have some starting guidelines from professional People out there like how they do it and what they use also

1.I want to develop Android Applications can you suggest me Simulator as well as good Starting Point(like links to tutorials)?

2.I have worked on c/c++/c# so is it going to be hard to learn Android?

> I know this is a bit theoretical
>   question that may invoke long
>   discussions but i wanted to set
>   starting point not only for me but for
>   others who see this thread so that
>   they do not have to post question,Yet
>   get answer that how it is
>   professionally done

Comment: Have you even tried reading the documentation?

Comment: not complete ,I just wanted to know what people use like it is good to know how different people do same thing

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: Well [android_official_docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html) are very good now, still you may like to check set off tutorials I have posted for android learning [**here**](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need the [android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) (including emulator)
2. You should learn "android" as an operating system / middleware, but the applications are written in Java (using android SDK as well). The tutorials and documentation that are in the [android developers' site](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) are pretty good and will give you the basics, but **you should learn Java** in order to create applications on android.

Unlike other "Documentation sites", the android documentation is really really helpful and easy to understand for new-comers.

p.s. I am ignoring native code and C libraries in purpose.

Comment: and i have also seen Mono on some discussions please have a word about it too

Comment: By and large, what is done is to use the official tools and recommended path, at least until you become familiar with specific limitations where the less supported and/or experimental alternatives might provide a benefit, or better support a specific effort that starts out with the goal not of doing 'mobile development' but of porting a specific existing codebase to a mobile platform.